# GridView1.EditIndex = -1 not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that works in edit mode but after updating, it does not go back into normal (non-edit) mode. `gridview.EditIndex = -1` is not working.

Here is the design:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="" HeaderText="Action">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-primary"
            Text="<i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' style='color:black'></i>  Update"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnlCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-success"
            Text="<i class='fa fa-ban' style='color:black'></i>  Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkedit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-primary" Text="<i class='fa fa-pencil' style='color:black'></i>  Edit"
            CommandName="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNotify" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-success"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to send notification?')"
            Text="<i class='fa fa-bell-o' style='color:black'></i>  Notify" OnClick="Notify"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?')"
            Text="<i class='fa fa-trash-o' style='color:black'></i>  Delete" OnClick="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is the C# code:

```
protected void UpdateInfo(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        new dalSchool().UpdateLandInfo(row, Session["Uid"].ToString());
        BindData();
        gv.EditIndex = -1;
        MessageController.Show(MessageCode.UpdateSucceeded, MessageType.Confirmation, Page);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageController.Show(MessageCode.UpdateFailed, MessageType.Error, Page);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `EditIndex` *before* you bind the GridView.

```
protected void UpdateInfo(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        new dalSchool().UpdateLandInfo(row, Session["Uid"].ToString());
        gv.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
        MessageController.Show(MessageCode.UpdateSucceeded, MessageType.Confirmation, Page);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageController.Show(MessageCode.UpdateFailed, MessageType.Error, Page);
    }
}
```